# Can't determine type for tag

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new here. I am a student at a vocational college in Germany. During lessons we are supposed to develop a game via Android Studio. Now I get the following error message in the file "values.xml" and can't get any further: `Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">attr/colorSurface</macro>'`

Informations about the IDE:

- Android API 32

I would appreciate helpful comments. If you need more information, feel free to ask me.

Yours sincerely

ayildi

Comment: please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16320675) and edit the question accordingly. The image can be included as *additional* information. Danke.

Comment: What file causes this error? Where do you have this `<macro>` tag? Please [edit] your question to include some code to give us the context of the problem.

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74191324. Possibly the same course, I suppose.