# macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>' error solution

Tags: android

macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface' error solution

solution
for
macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface' error solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74190460

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by this.

dependencies {
implementation""
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was running the old project which was running properly, but when I ran it after and year I got this error I found out that it was because of the react-native-screens package which was written in package.json like this "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1", so I fixed it by doing this "react-native-screens": "3.13.1",

~version “Approximately equivalent to version”, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.

^version “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <2.0.0